# How many proprietary mapping api we can use in android other than Google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

How may mapping api's could be possible to use in android other than Google map, as i know few options are Microsoft Bing, Map Quest, Open Layers, Leaflet, Modest Map, Polymaps etc. Which mapping will be good to use in android other that Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps works well. Here are some details on how to do this:
http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/28/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap.aspx
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cross-Platform-Bing-Maps-e96600d5

Also take a look at chapter 11 of my free ebook on creating location intelligent apps with Bing Maps: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/